# Concourse github-release resource cannot find older versions or tags

Tags: concourse

I'm trying to pull an older version/tags of a git hub release in my Concourse pipeline using the github-release-resource, but it does not seem to be able to find releases other than the latest one though.
Here is the simple test where we try to extract an older release of concourse itself.

```
---
resources:
- name: concourse-release
  type: github-release
  source:
    user: concourse
    repository: concourse
    access_token: YOUR-GITHUB-ACCESS-TOKEN-GOES-HERE
jobs:
- name: test-concourse-release
  plan:
  - do:
    - get: concourse-release
      version: { tag: 'v2.4.0' }
    - task: test-release
      config:
        platform: linux
        image_resource:
          type: docker-image
          source:
            repository: ubuntu
        inputs:
        - name: concourse-release
        run:
          path: sh
          args:
          - -exc
          - |
            find .
            cat ./concourse-release/tag
            cat ./concourse-release/version
```

The resource output for the task above is:

```
waiting for a suitable set of input versions
concourse-release - pinned version {"tag":"v2.4.0"} is not available
```

even though the release exists: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/tag/v2.4.0

How can I get that to work?

Answer (score 4):

According to Concourse documentation, newly configured resources will only start from the latest version.

You have to use the `fly` CLI with command [`check-resource`](https://concourse.ci/fly-check-resource.html) in order to have an older version of the resource downloaded.

For example, for the sample pipeline listed in the question, this would be the command to retrieve the older version (v2.4.0) of Concourse and make it available for the pipeline execution:

```
fly -t <your-target-alias> check-resource --resource <your-pipeline-name>/concourse-release --from tag:v2.4.0
```