# How do I use an older version of a resource in my Concourse pipeline?

Tags: concourse

Resource `check` scripts in Concourse will emit the most recent version of a resource by default. For example, configuring a [git -resource](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource) in your pipeline to point to a git repository's master branch will emit the latest commit SHA as the version.

For some resources, (eg. the [github-release resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108427)) you may not want to use just the latest version emitted by the check script; you may want an older version of that resource that isn't the latest one at the time of configuring your pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fly check-resource` command lets you force the `check` for a resource to run, and there is an optional flag to force checking from a given version in the past.

eg.

`fly check-resource --resource some-pipeline/some-git-resource --from  ref:123abcsomecommithash`

or

`fly check-resource --resource some-pipeline/some-github-release-resource --from tag:v1.2.3`

**Note** that the version passed to the `--from` flag is *resource dependant*, so you will need to pass a version reference that matches the resource you are checking; you can see this by clicking on the resource in the UI and viewing the version history details.